# How to attain minimum time dealy in rendering texture in SDL2?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I  tested how much  millisecond it takes to render 1280*720 picture into the texture by below code.  I got the result in milliseconds in between the values (47 to 75) .

Due to this , i get the latency, as  i m trying to display 30 frames per second, which means maximum of 33.3 milliseconds is needed to render.

1)  Is it the right way of measuring the time frame?

2)  Any quirk i need to be aware of ?

```
  startingTime = SDL_GetTicks ();
  SDL_UpdateYUVTexture(bmp, NULL, pFrame->data[0], pFrame->linesize[0], 
                                  pFrame->data[1], pFrame->linesize[1],
                                  pFrame->data[2], pFrame->linesize[2]);


  SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
  SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, bmp, NULL, NULL);
  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

  eTime = SDL_GetTicks (); 
  printf (" Time taken for Rendering... %ld ", eTime - sTime);
```

**PS NOTE:**

I have tested with each API, where it look, SDL_UpdateYUVTexture takes most of the milliseconds, whereas other API's take hardly 0 to 1 ms. Rest of the time is occupied by SDL_UpdateTexture.

Comment: How much time does it take *without* the texture upload?

Comment: genpfault, It looks SDL_UpdateYUVTexture takes most of the time, and rest of the API's hardly about 0 to 1 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Try using OPENGLES library for rendering the frames in the screen,SDL_UpdateYUVTexture() api will generally takes more time for update.